# How to compare month of today with a column name in SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have columns like this in the `ProjectDates` table:

```
PDID (primary), ProjectID, D01072016, D02072016, D03072016 etc.
```

I want to select only those columns where the current month matches the month of the column name.

For ex, D01072016 (month 07) does not match current month of today i.e 09. So this column should not be selected in the view.

How to make a select statement for this condition?

Comment: Bad table design, don't have different columns for different months. Have one common column, and several rows instead.

Comment: A view is a **static**, stored SQL statement - it cannot "automagically" adapt itself dynamically every month .... and I have to agree with @jarlh: this is a ***horribly bad*** table design!

Comment: As others have said, it's a bad idea. You now have *data*, that you want to write queries about, embedded in your *metadata* instead of as normal data. Just about every query you have to write against such a table will prove to be problematic. It looks like it's been designed around a particular mode of *presentation*, rather than by modelling the *data*.

Comment: Now that we have entered the good or bad design mode... let me take it further.

The table has a primary key(seq number) , Project ID related to projects table, Task ID
related to Task Table and all the dates in the year as column names.
The 'dates' columns are char fields filled with markers like y, n, c etc.
This 'marking' is done thro a stored proc.

Now I want to show the users the data pertaining to the current month and beyond.
So the need to get only those 'dates' columns.

Now what is 'bad' in this design. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT PDID,
   CASE MONTH(GETDATE())
   WHEN 1 THEN D01012016
   WHEN 2 THEN D01022016
   ...
   WHEN 12 THEN D01122016
   END AS D01CRT2016,
   CASE MONTH(GETDATE())
   WHEN 1 THEN D02012016
   WHEN 2 THEN D02022016
   ...
   WHEN 12 THEN D02122016
   END AS D02CRT2016,
FROM ...
```

Repeat as needed for every day of the month, up to 31. Good luck handling leap years.

Answer (score 1):

You can get column list from

```
 select * from information_schema.columns 
 where table_name='ProjectDates' and column_name like '%07%'
```

You need to construct a dynamic query like...

```
declare @qry nvarchar(max)
set @qry = 'select '
select @qry = @qry + '[' + column_name +'],'
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='ProjectDates ' and column_name like '%07%'  -- month
set @qry = left(@qry ,len(@qry )-1) 
set @qry = @qry + ' from ProjectDates '
exec sp_executesql @qry
```